# Sql Service Reporting In Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

i create sucessfully sql report in asp.net using visual stduio 2008 with sql server 2008 r2

i have a report name report1.rdll

now i have a form admin option and i add tab like reports

html

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="reprtpanel">
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <span>

         Reports 

            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    </asp:Panel>
```

it show me like this

[image report](http://i41.tinypic.com/vhxo9k.png)

then any one please tell me how i call sql report ...

Answer (score 1):

From the **toolox**-> **Reporting** drag a **reportViewer** control on your aspx page.
Then from design view click on the arrow o the viewer to select the rdlc report that you created, as shown in the image

[image]

that should load your report on the aspx page

**UPDATE:**
to configure the reports from remote server you can follow the steps from this 2 articles

1. [Adding and Configuring the ReportViewer Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252104%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. [Using the WebForms ReportViewer Control](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337091.aspx)

Comment: plz zee my update3 question i add image in my side in choose report it show me only server report,report server url,report path and when enter report1.rdl in report path it cann not show me report..how to reslove this please image which i posted @Raphael

Comment: I found 2 articles that explain how to use rdl reports. I usually develop the reports inside my project.